# How to join tables where a variable number of conditions match

Tags: sql, join, pivot

I have two tables, tblPerson and tblOffer.  The person table has details about which products they currently have.  The offers have multiple criteria for whether or not we should suggest that a person get the new product.

I'm trying to join these based on multiple criteria in tblOffer, but getting stuck on making sure that all of the selected criteria are judged, not just any one of them.  For example Here are some fields in my tables.

```
tblPerson
pkPersonId
HasCreditCard
HasEmail
HasLoan

tblOffer
pkOfferId
NeedsCreditCard
NeedsEmail
NeedsLoan
```

Sample Data:

```
tblPerson
1, 0, 0, 1
2, 0, 1, 0
3, 0, 0, 0

tblOffer
100, 1, 0, 1
200, 0, 0, 1
300, 1, 1, 0
```

I'm trying to return a result for person 1 which contains Offer 300, Person 2 gets offer 100 and 200, and Person 3 gets offers 100, 200, and 300.

I have tried Cross APPLY between the two tables, and then using my WHERE clause to say:

```
SELECT * FROM tblPerson prs
        CROSS JOIN tblMrmOffer ofr
    WHERE prs.pkPersonId = @PersonId AND (
            (prs.HasEmail = 0 AND ofr.NeedsEmail = 1) OR 
            (prs.HasCreditCard = 0 AND ofr.NeedsCreditCard = 1) OR
            (prs.HasLoan = 0 AND ofr.NeedsLoan = 1))
```

This will give me a row if any of the selected criteria are true but not limited to rows where all selected criteria are set.  For example, Offer 300 would match if the person needs a Credit Card or Email, but not necessarily if they need both.  I'm trying to work this out as a Cross Tab Pivot, but not clear how to JOIN this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *For example, Offer 300 would match if the person needs a Credit Card or Email, but not necessarily if they need both*: what do you mean? Offer 300 would match all three people in your data. Could you please post the desired resultset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make it so that only offers show up for which each of the items in the offer are needed by a person, but offers are disqualified if the person already has at least one of the things, then here is some SQL to try.  What each of the AND conditions says is we want to disqualify cases where the person already has an item in the offer.

```
SELECT * FROM tblPerson prs
    CROSS JOIN tblMrmOffer ofr
WHERE prs.pkPersonId = @PersonId
  AND
    NOT (prs.HasEmail = 1 AND ofr.NeedsEmail = 1)
  AND
    NOT (prs.HasCreditCard = 1 AND ofr.NeedsCreditCard = 1)
  AND
    NOT (prs.HasLoan = 1 AND ofr.NeedsLoan = 1)
```

If instead, you are looking for cases where the offer has ALL of the person's needs, then this SQL might be more up your alley.  The theory with the case statements is if the criteria IS important (which is the case when the HasX = 0), then the filter needs to be 1 for the NeedsX.  Otherwise, it just matches the NeedsX value (and so the filter wouldn't do anything).

```
SELECT * FROM tblPerson prs
    CROSS JOIN tblMrmOffer ofr
WHERE prs.pkPersonId = @PersonId
  AND
      (
        ofr.NeedsEmail
        =
        CASE
          WHEN prs.HasEmail = 0
          THEN 1
          ELSE ofr.NeedsEmail
        END
      )
  AND
      (
        ofr.NeedsCreditCard
        =
        CASE
          WHEN prs.HasCreditCard = 0
          THEN 1
          ELSE ofr.NeedsCreditCard
        END
      )
  AND
      (
        ofr.NeedsLoan
        =
        CASE
          WHEN prs.HasLoan = 0
          THEN 1
          ELSE ofr.NeedsLoan
        END
      )
```

If you want to get really fancy, you can, in your select statement, put a ranking that ranks cases that perfectly match the person's needs above those that just match some of the user's unmet needs.  For this, it would look something like this, which prioritizes perfect matches first, and good matches second (and within good matches, those with more items in the offer), and then within those categories, latest offers first:

```
SELECT
  ...
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY prs.pkPersonID
    ORDER BY
      CASE
        WHEN <logic from 2nd SQL above>
        THEN 1
        WHEN <logic from 1st SQL above>
        THEN ofr.NeedsEmail + ofr.NeedsCreditCard + ofr.NeedsLoan
        ELSE NULL
      END,
      ofr.pkOfferId DESC
  ) AS Order
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I may have explained (or designed) this a bit improperly.  I expanded on your second suggestion because I'm not clear that it would work if the users just don't select NeedsEmail because having an Email may not matter to the offer.  I made it a bit looser by using WHERE clause CASEs like this: 

(CASE WHEN ofr.NeedsEmail = 1 THEN CASE WHEN cch.HasEmail = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE 1 END = 1) AND ...